can this faucet be adapted to fit
When we purchased this home 5 years ago it came with this vintage faucet and we really liked it. It has been nothing but trouble and I'm finally just going to bite the bullet and replace it.
I've now got this faucet which I'm hoping can work. I do have access via a panel outside the wall.
I had some plumbers come by and it sounds like maybe the existing bits/pieces aren't compatible with this, but i really wanna try to make it work if possible. Its difficult to even shop for this style of faucet. I'm also open literally anything else at this point that could be used as a replacement given I have wall access.
sidenote: i would consider maybe just getting it to stop leaking. if anybody has an idea on these older faucets and CONSTANT leaking, I'm all ears.



I'm sure your new faucet could be made to work.
It's great that you have axcess to the wall behind the tub. A good plumber will be able to adapt any existing plumbing to the new faucet.
I looked at the dimensions info of the new faucet and it looks like the "spread" or the distance between the hot and cold supply lines is adjustable.  The supply hook up is 1/2"NPT which is very common. So the new faucet should be a fairly easy swap with some work by the plumber, but nothing outrageous. That is unless there is a giant mess of plumbing in the wall.

thanks for the response! the spread is identical as far as I can tell. There are some included riser arms which seem to allow for a variance of distance if needed.
the biggest concerns are the adjustments needed for the shower head as the length and distance from the wall are going to change.

Yes, I edited my answer...i looked at the specs.

The shower head in the new unit is hand held.   If you want a mounted shower head, that should be an easy conversion for the plumber, since the pipe is outside the wall.

Also, fortunately, that tile looks pretty generic—if any replacement is needed (breakage during removal, hole relocation/removal, etc.), should be easy to locate.
